# How do i go pass an integer's value of 2^62 -1 in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, int

How may i actually specify a for loop with an iterator value larger than an int's max size?

i.e. i would like to loop 2^62 -1 times.

**EDIT**: 2^62 -1

Comment: erm, what? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: use a long: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Comment: Your question heading and body don't match by a factor of more than one billion. ;)

Comment: If you plan to have dinner after executing this code I would suggest getting some snacks before you start ...

Comment: My BOTE calculations suggest that at 1 billion loops per second, this will take about 146.5 years.  Are you patient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(long i = 0; i < (1L << 62) - 1; ++i){
    //loop
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `1L << 62` otherwise this is the same as `1 << 30` ;)

Comment: You also want to start at `i = 1` or `i < (1L << 62) - 1` otherwise it will be 2^62. :P

Comment: To the OP - get your grandchildren to let us know when the loop finished :-)

Answer (score 4):

That will take you essentially forever on the hardware of today and the foreseeable future.

Try and refine your algorithm to be more efficient.

Comment: It's a true comment on the question, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: +1: No idea the reason for the downvote. It will take about 100 years, unless the loop is empty in which case it will take about 2 seconds on the server JVM.

Comment: Maybe, He want's an answer not the truth. :)

Comment: Sometimes the best answer/advise is to tell someone not to do it.

Comment: @Mobinga Maybe he doesn't know that. In all honestly, is there any reason why you would ever want to loop 2^62 - 1 times? The -1 in the number of iterations makes me think this is just a bad approach to a math problem.

Comment: If he tries it, he learns. I didn't dv you though, what if he has the ability to compute that or something similar?

Comment: Then we should tremble in fear, because anyone with hardware capable of that kind of computing power either A) has connections to ultra-intelligent extraterrestrial life B) has a farm of quantum computers

Comment: +1 - for attempting to bring a touch of reality to this ludicrous question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `long`s for your loop counters and use `long` literals in your loop test (e.g. `1000000000000L`). If `long`s are too small for you, you can use `BigInteger`.

As other answers have stated, you will be waiting for a long long time for your loops to end. tell us how it goes when its done :).